# Create TKinter label using class method

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am trying use object oriented programming style to write the code for a Tkinter app. I want to use a class method to place labels(or other widgets) to the GUI. The code I wrote is adding a character which I don't expect to the GUI.  How can I write the initial ***add_label method*** so that it does not add the unwanted character.
Below is my code and a screenshot. I am new to OOP, so i might be missing something.

```
from tkinter import *
class App:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.widgets(root)
        self.add_label(root)

    def widgets(self, app):
        self.title = Label(app, text= 'LABEL UP').pack()
        self.btn = Button(app, text = 'BUTTON').pack()
    def add_label(self, text):
        Label(text= text).pack()

root = Tk()
App(root)
App.add_label(root, 'LABEL_1')
App.add_label(root,'LABEL_2')
root.mainloop()
```

[image]
I am new to OOP and stil trying to figure out how i can benefit from code reuse in this case. My app has several widgets and functions

Comment: Can you explain giving an example of what you want and what you got?

Comment: @CoolCloud addes the screenshot

Comment: Remove `self.add_label(root)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you expect `self.add_label(root)` to do? According to your method definition, it takes `text` as argument, so when you say `self.add_label(root)`, you are passing `root` as `text`. And what is `root`? It is `'.'`, so remove it and it'll be gone.

Though a proper way to do this will be to pass a `parent` argument to the method and use that while widget creation:

And the important part is, your instantiating the `class` wrong. Keep a reference to it, rather than creating a lot of instances.

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.widgets(root)

    def widgets(self, app):
        self.title = Label(app, text= 'LABEL UP').pack()
        self.btn = Button(app, text = 'BUTTON').pack()
    
    def add_label(self, parent, text):
        Label(parent,text= text).pack()

root = Tk()

app = App(root)
app.add_label(root, 'LABEL_1')
app.add_label(root,'LABEL_2')

root.mainloop()
```

Try not to get confused with both the mistakes.

How would I write this class? I don't know the true purpose of this, but I think you can follow something like this:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        
        self.title = Label(self.parent, text='LABEL UP')
        self.title.pack()

        self.entry = Entry(self.parent)
        self.entry.pack()

        self.btn = Button(self.parent, text='BUTTON')
        # Compliance with PEP8
        self.btn.config(command=lambda: self.add_label(self.entry.get())) 
        self.btn.pack()

    def add_label(self, text):
        Label(self.parent, text=text).pack()

    def start(self):
        self.parent.mainloop()

root = Tk()

app = App(root)
app.start()
```

Comment: I would be interested to see any other option as you stated (...Though a proper way to do this will be to pass a parent argument to the method and use that while widget creation...)

Comment: @mapperx More options? The code I included is the best way current code can be modified to(IMO). Or you can surely just restructure your code. You would not need to make a method to create labels. It is just one line of code, do that manually. Functions on different widgets that are reusable can be made onto a method. And almost all variables are `None` in your code.

Comment: @mapperx Check the updated answer to see an alternative structuring.

Comment: Just for clarity, what does the 'parent' stand for in your implementation and why do you choose to add the start method. I get the basics of the code. I am really trying to understand OOP better.
Gone through some materials already but challenging for me to implement it into solving real life problems.

Comment: @mapperx `parent` is the root window, the main window. I just added `start` because, that is what people usually. Keep codes within the class, rather than write using class initialization.

Comment: Clear and understood.